# What is the best way to retrieve table from MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, data-retrieval

I just have `SELECT` query which returns table. I don't like to type this query into PHP scripts. I want to create functions and procedures to retrieve data so I just call from PHP, and so it works properly with `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements. But I can't return table!

So what is the best way to get table data from MySQL to PHP without typing query into PHP page?

Comment: I see two other options: Use a stored procedure in your MySQL db or use some ORM system, which handles all the DB-related stuff for you....

Comment: Can you post an example of one of these update/delete functions you've created?

Comment: about update/delete it is procedure which take input
I've created them using PHPmyadmin GUI ... it is simple and easy
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateGame`(IN `game_id` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER UPDATE `MYDB`.`games` SET `status` = '1' WHERE `games`.`id` = game_id

Comment: It sounds like you are using phpMyAdmin at the moment, and want to know how to issue SQL statements programmatically inside a web application. If so, everyone misunderstood your question. You need to look into mysqli or PDO, which are libraries supplied by PHP for the purposes of running database queries in your application. You can indeed use an ORM (as per VeeeneX's answer) but it is best to understand the basics first.

Comment: @halfer
 actually I know how to retrieve data and send sql queries ... but the problem just because I don't like to type sql statements into php page for some problems like 'sql injection' and also for clean code for more readability ... I just want to use functions/procedures instead of typing
this works fine with update, delete
the main problem for me was that I can't return table from procedures 
but it looks works now for me ... 
just I don't need to put return type or return parameter ...
just put select statement into procedure it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use frameworks for this:

- [Medoo](http://medoo.in/)
- Orm system

If you have to run same query, you can create a procedure in MySQL as Sirko said.

Comment: thank you very much
I will search about ORM .. medoo

Answer (score -1):

The simple Way would be to use php class mysqli.

Comment: How would that solve OPs problem? The queries would still be part of the PHP source code.